# Angular Typescript error trying to reference implemented class property

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing Angular ErrorHandler class.

In `app.module.ts` providers I have:

```
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
```

Then in the implemented class, GlobalErrorHandler, I have:

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  public errorAdded$: EventEmitter<string>;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.errorAdded$ = new EventEmitter();
  }
```

TypeScript complains when I try to reference the `errorAdded$` property from another service where it gets injected:

```
@Injectable()
export class AlertService {
   private subject = new Subject<Alert>();
   private keepAfterRouteChange = false;

   constructor(private router: Router, private errorService: ErrorHandler) {
       errorService.errorAdded$.subscribe((error) => this.error(error));
    }
    //...
  }
```

If I try to inject GlobalErrorHandler I get an error.

What should I do to reference `errorAdded$` properly (properties on the GlobalErrorHandler class when it is injected into other classes?)

Comment: But what is the error?

Comment: Error in bail mode: [at-loader] ./src/app/alerts/_services/alert.service.ts:17:26 
    TS2339: Property 'errorAdded$' does not exist on type 'ErrorHandler'.

Comment: That's right, it doesn't. It only exists on `GlobalErrorHandler`s.

Comment: yes, it make sense. Better way is inject `AlertService ` into `GlobalErrorHandler `

Comment: So how do I inject GlobalErrorHandler? If I try to inject it, I get this error: Error: No provider for GlobalErrorHandler!

Comment: Workaround is to use bracket syntax and Typescript issue is resolved.            errorService['errorAdded$'].subscribe((error) => this.error(error));

Comment: @lance-p that's barely even a workaround, you might as well not be using TS at that point. You could inject it directly if you made it a provider in its own right, it would actually be simpler than the current provider definition.

Comment: Thanks Jon. That was part of my original question. When I try adding a GlobalErrorHandler provider, and pass it into the constructor it doesn't work. Do I create a new provider and use it in GlobalErrorHandler to reference the errorAdded$ property, then inject it into the AlertService?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you write a solution as an answer? I have the same problem trying to use a method defined in useClass, as in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paginator-intl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapples%2Fapples%2Fapples.component.ts). setLabel throws a typescript 2339 does not exist error. (But the browser runs it just fine)